# Type guard that asserts all rest parameters are not undefined

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Is it possible to make a user defined type guard that will let the compiler know that all of the arguments passed to it are defined?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
  public static all(...values: unknown[]): values is object[] {
    return values.every(value => typeof(value) !== 'undefined');
  }
```

I'd like to use this so that I can pass a set of arguments that are potentially undefined, handle what happens if they are undefined, and otherwise pass them to a method that requires value are not undefined.

That might look like this:

```
    if (!ParamHelper.all(id, ...dateParts)) { return []; }
    const date = new Date(dateParts.join('-'));
    const result = await this.service.getData(assetId, date);
```

When I try the naive version above, the compiler tells me:

> a type predicate cannot reference a rest parameter

So, I'm currently assuming it can't be done.  But, I figured I'd ask before giving up.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't guard multiple values at the same time. Not sure that is required for your example however: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcwFsASBTEAHdDoG8AoaE6LAVwCMQBLYaCAFzEbujBBAB4AVadAB6N0AOwAmMciIDWIgPYB3EQG0AugD4AFADcO5dBABc0HgEpjukPpg0YRUg+jLY0GiOjT0ATzkAzE6rGAKICoORi6LzOqgA00FIRvm7oYurEpAC+BOmO0AjojOQI7pbWAHTo2rheOnro0AC86tCMXjh+0LVW6KbQAIQNDdAA5AnoSSIpw6YA3DnQGYSLvlLArHLuAgKaYizo8AiMRtAAgghIXlxMCG4A5tAAPvHi48mpvRZyNGL2pDT+mj6BxQGGwuDKHBAOz2ByOpl6+DyBSK7jUMwWhHmwA2TGgu2EjWgkwU0AAIntocJYRAygArL4iTTDAC001mSyAA

Comment: Type guards only act on usefully on single variables.  The rest parameter is either multiple parameters (in which case you could only affect one of them), or it's a single array that you can't access outside of the function implementation (in which case the narrowing is not observable to you).  Either way, it doesn't work .  I think you'll need to do `const a = [id, ...dateParts]; if (!all(a){}{})` where `all` is of type `(x: unknown[])=>x is object[]`.  (note that `null` is not considered assignable to `object` in TypeScript; might be a wrinkle in your implementation.)

Comment: Both of those are super clever!  TypeScript is amazing!  They don't quite get me to a point where I can somewhat arbitrarily assert that a set of variables have values.  I mean, they do if they're the same type.  It's presently easier for me to say `if (!id || !day || !month || !year) { return; }`.

Comment: @jcalz, you could include your comment as an answer. The point that rest parameters could be one thing shows why it's best to just inline what is being checked for me.

Comment: TypeScript GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26916

Comment: @jcalz what about with rest/spread types?

Comment: I am hoping someone can explain the conclusion of the comments here. Perhaps make it an answer 